# Collection view Flow layout similar to Apple Store Application

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am using `UICollectionView` for displaying images like as in Apple Store iPhone Application . (Screenshots attached)

But I am not able to set a flow layout similar to Apple store app. I am facing issues in setting it's layout and content offset and inset . I tried every thing ,even subclassing it's flow layout. Even that didn't work for me.

```
- (CGPoint)targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset:(CGPoint)proposedContentOffset withScrollingVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity

- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
```

I also tried to implement `iCarousel` for same ,but it didn't work as well.

Any help related to flow layout appreciated. Also, if there is any other solution apart from using collection view .

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Update :**

I have implemented following code to set it's flow layout using [NDCollectionViewFlowLayout](https://gist.github.com/nicksnyder/4075682):

```
NDCollectionViewFlowLayout *nda = [[NDCollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
nda.itemSize = CGSizeMake(251, 443);
nda.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
nda.minimumLineSpacing = 15.0;
nda.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10.0;
nda.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
```

Each and everything just like Appstore image layout.

**UPDATE :**

I finally ended up using `iCarousel`,with some modifications in it.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?  You may be very close with one simple mistake... so it'd be useful to actually see what you've tried and your actual results.

Comment: @nhgrif : Thanks for the quick response .I have updated my question . Even I think,I am missing something but not getting the hint of it.

Answer (score 1):

[Example project here](https://github.com/danya0365/appstore-collectionview-swift)

In class perperty

```
     var itemSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
     @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
     @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
     fileprivate let sectionInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

In viewDidLoad or awakeFormNib(If in collectionViewCell or tableViewCell)

```
    if let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    }
    collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 16, bottom: 0, right: 8)
    collectionView.isPagingEnabled = false
    layoutIfNeeded()

    let width = collectionView.bounds.size.width-24
    let height = width * (3/4)
    itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    layoutIfNeeded()
```

Implement UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

        return sectionInsets
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return itemSize
    }
```

Implement ScrollViewDelegate

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    let pageWidth = itemSize.width
    targetContentOffset.pointee = scrollView.contentOffset
    var factor: CGFloat = 0.5
    if velocity.x < 0 {
        factor = -factor
        print("right")
    } else {
        print("left")
    }

    let a:CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.x/pageWidth
    var index = Int( round(a+factor) )
    if index < 0 {
        index = 0
    }
    if index > collectionViewDataList.count-1 {
        index = collectionViewDataList.count-1
    }
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
    collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .left, animated: true)
}
```

See example screenshot from my project at Past rides section
I have implemented uicollectionview in collectionViewCell

[image]